# Are background variables thread-safe in karate mock?

Tags: karate

I am using [karate-mock](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty) with the following `.feature` file:

```
Feature: test feature

  Background:
    * def testData = {};

  # setting test-data
  Scenario: pathMatches('/test-data') && methodIs('post')
    * testData[request.data.key] = request.data
    * def responseStatus = 200

  # some other scenarios which are working with test-data
```

In the [docs](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty/#capabilities) it is written that `karate-mock` is thread-safe, but it is not clear if this includes variables or not.

For example, we make three requests in parallel to the endpoint above:

```
first request body:  {"data":{"key":"1", "field":"field-value"}}
second request body: {"data":{"key":"2", "field":"field-value"}}
third request body:  {"data":{"key":"3", "field":"field-value"}}
```

Is there any chance that some keys will be lost or `testData` variable is thread-safe?

Comment: as far as I know things are thread-safe karate mocks locks the whole request on a thread until it returns. if you provide a way to replicate, we can certainly look at fixing issues.